# What is the birth-time, birth-date, birth-place (and possibly birth-chart) of this site?

Tags: discussion, community

Is it possible to get the date and time this site 'Hinduism Stack Exchange' was formed? Also is it possible to know where the servers are located? We might be able to form a birth chart for our site based on all this information. Pieces of information needed are:

- Date of the formation
- Time of the formation
- Place of the formation (use server location?)

*Even if the exact time of formation is not available, we may be able to form a Chandra Kundali based on the date of formation!*

If the information is available to the moderator of this site and if the moderator is capable of making a birth chart then the moderator can answer the above information along with the birth chart formed, else some other user of this site who knows Vedic astrology can form birth chart and post based on information provided!

Other Panchangam details like Rashi, Nakshatra, Tithi, Vara, Yoga, etc.. of that date-time-place will also be useful to know! Also if information about which Dasha our site is currently running is available it would be useful!

Comment: Welcome back! I think all this information is available in public domain.. let me post answer in evening.

Comment: i doubt that janma patrika is applicable to Achit which doesn't have janma :)

Comment: @mar I think In Samhita/ mundane Astrology, we can create Janma patrika for any entity that was created, even if it is intangible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hinduism page on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/53689/revisions) says site was proposed on *April 12, 2013 at 12:03:08* Z. Time Zone is UTC as mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27201). So, *April 12, 2013 at 12:03:08 UTC.*

Now, user [manishearth](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/52181/manishearth) seems to be in *Mumbai* when he proposed this site. But i'm not sure if we have to consider location as Mumbai or location of servers. Although user created site through "a click" from *Mumbai*, servers seem to be place of creation. As mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10370) and [this blog page](https://blog.serverfault.com/2010/10/29/1432571770/), Data centers are in Newyork city. Since New york city is vast, we can get exact latitude and longitude of Stack exchange office from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact). So, exact values are *40°42'31.7"N 74°00'24.6"W*

I'll give date in both IST (for Mumbai) and EDT (for Newyork City).

[Mumbai](https://savvytime.com/converter/utc-to-ist/apr-12-2013/12-03pm) - April 12, 2013 at 5:33:08 PM

[New York city](https://savvytime.com/converter/utc-to-ny-new-york-city/apr-12-2013/12-03pm) - April 12, 2013 at 8:03:08 AM

Now i'll share what [Jagannatha Hora](https://www.vedicastrologer.org/jh/) generates (D1 and D9) for two places with *Lahari Ayanamsa* in both South Indian and North Indian formats.

**Mumbai**:

[image]

**Panchanga details**:

[image]

**Newyork City**:

[image]

**Panchanga details**:

[image]

Key Points we observe:

> 1. New York location has *Vrishabha lagna* while Mumbai has *Kanya lagna*.
> 2. Tithi and Nakshatra are same in both locations which are Sukla Trittiya of Chaitra Masa (Amanta) and Bharani 3rd pada respectively.
> 3. Site is currently (18 May, 2021) in *Ravi Mahadasha and Guru Antardasha* (Vimshottari Dasa system) .

Comment: Wow! So when will HSE graduate? :)

Comment: @Pandya i'm still beginner . Not that advanced.

Answer (score 2):

TheDestroyer has already answered; just to make a point that both the locations are correct. Mumbai's location is the location of garbhadaan whereas NY's is the location of birth. We leverage location & timing of garbhadaan to fine tune birth timing for attaining birth time precise to seconds followed by creating dasha aarambh chakra.